# Safari searchbox doesn't save page in the history

Tags: safari, search

When I use searchbox (the same text area used for the URLs) and Google Page is loaded, after clicking on a result, if I try to undo to the previous Google Page, the undo button appears disabled. 
How can I save the Google Page in the history in order to call back the page clicking on undo button?

Update:
The problem appears only with same pages (e.g. Wikipedia).

Comment: Do you have the page open in a new tab?  If so, the "undo" or Back button  has no history for that tab.  What does your actual History show?  Menu bar **History**?

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, so to speak...Try a simple test. Cmd/T for new tab; type 'mac apps' in the search & Enter [first hit will probably be Apple Store] click that. Check there's a < arrow & that Cmd [ will return you to the Google page.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally, and I've been unable to reproduce it even with the same search query and page clicked.